# cmake find all directories by name on the include path and add them to the include path

Tags: cmake, configuration, include

I am working with a library that nominally stores its internal headers in a directory that is not itself on the include path, although its parent is. Including the intended entry point header ends up failing because it links to other internal headers via quoted include without the directory name.

I do `#include <SDL2/SDL.h>` which the compiler does find, in `/usr/include/SDL2/SDL.h` on my system, but it then fails to find "begin_code.h" which is included several layers deeper in SDLs internal header code.

```c
In file included from /usr/include/SDL2/SDL.h:32:
In file included from /usr/include/SDL2/SDL_main.h:25:
In file included from /usr/include/SDL2/SDL_stdinc.h:31:
In file included from /usr/include/SDL2/SDL_config.h:4:
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/SDL2/_real_SDL_config.h:33:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/SDL2/SDL_platform.h:179:10: fatal error: 'begin_code.h' file not found
#include "begin_code.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

Adding `-iquote /usr/include/SDL2` manually works in my case, but what about in build environments where the SDL2 headers were downloaded to some local directory? The point of cmake is to work with local configurations that vary, so adding a hard-coded single path based on platform would be dumb. I want some future person who wants to compile my code with the SDL2 headers downloaded to `~/projects/headers/SDL2` to be able to compile after specifying only `~/projects/headers` to their include path, for example, so they don't have to deal with SDLs internal issues.

It seems to me that all I need is to iterate on every dir on the -iquote path and, if it contains a directory name SDL2, add that directory to the -iquote. Does cmake make available the (system configuration dependent) -iquote path as an traversable list?

This question is my attempt to rephrase [this unasnwered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68170919/cmake-find-system-include-directory-not-by-name-or-content-c-c-relative) for clarity.

**Edit:** I get that cmake is not *responsible* for fixing the issue, but cmake (or, rather, a CMakeList.txt file in my project) should be *capable* of working around this SDL bug. Hard-coding the assumed path is only reliable for build systems that install SDL2 headers via some standard package manager. I've never seen a unix dev manually download header files and stick them in the system include path, for fear that they might be overwritten or otherwise conflict with a future install of an official headers package. There are other valid places to put include files, so cmake should be able to search them. Isn't eliminating hard-coded paths half the point of cmake?

Comment: @Tsyvarev please see edit

Comment: I was not blaming cmake for not adding it. I was asking how to use cmake properly.

Comment: @Tsyvarev that did not work. Still getting the same error about begin_code.h being missing.

Comment: OK, it seems that script `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/SDL2/sdl2-config.cmake`, which is part of the package [libsdl2-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/libsdl2-dev/filelist), is wrong. By itself, CMake can do nothing about that problem. As a fix, you could call something like `find_path(SDL_INC_DIR1 "begin_code.h" PATH_SUFFIXES "SDL2")` and add `${SDL_INC_DIR1}` to the list of include directories. That way you will avoid hardcodes.

Comment: That works, although I was trying to avoid counting on the name of that file, seeing as SDL has every right to change the name of that file without warning. So that brings us back to the original question: can I simply add all folders named "SDL2" that happen to be under an existing include path dir to the include path. Picking up the wrong folder a couple times would be harmless and more future-proof and therefore preferable.

Comment: For the future, if existing approach is failing for you, then specify that approach in the question post (or simply add **your code**). With the current state of your question it is unclear **what you are trying**, and my thoughts was that you are have **none** SDL-related code in your `CMakeLists.txt`. That is why my previous comments was posted.

Comment: I am not posting the complete cmakelist.txt file for NDA-related reasons. You were correct in thinking that I had no SDL-related code in my CMakeList.txt file at the time, because everything I had tried had failed (other than the hard-coded path). I do not see how my question is unclear. I am just trying to compile with `#include SDL2/SDL.h` without a hard-coded path, which is explained.

Comment: "can I simply add all folders named "SDL2" that happen to be under an existing include path dir to the include path." - This is not how CMake is expected to be used. "I was trying to avoid counting on the name of that file, seeing as SDL has every right to change the name of that file without warning." - If you assume that "unknown" header is located in the same directory as `SDL.h`, then you could search that header instead: `find_path(SDL_INC_DIR1 "SDL.h" PATH_SUFFIXES "SDL2")`.

Comment: I don't know why I have to justify how I asked my question and why I didn't read every other answer first. You have solved the problem. If you kindly write up an answer with some of these I will accept it. Otherwise I have no interest in continuing this fairly pointless conversation in the comments section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CMake doesn't provide a way for a *custom* iteration over include directories.
Instead, you could reformulate your intentions into the form "find a directory with the given header".

That form is expressed with command [find_path](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_path.html), which is a natural way in CMake for search include directories.

E.g. that call:

```
# Task for CMake: Find a directory with "begin_code.h" header in it.
#   Possibly, this is subdirectory 'SDL2' of a "normal" include directory.
find_path(SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR_1 "begin_code.h" PATH_SUFFIXES "SDL2")
```

will fill the variable `SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR_1` with the directory containing the header `begin_code.h`.

This way works perfectly in case of local installation of SDL2, if that installation is hinted for CMake with `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` variable. For support other hints, e.g. `SDL2DIR` environment variable, you need to add appropriate `PATHS` options to your call:

```
find_path(SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR_1 "begin_code.h" PATH_SUFFIXES "SDL2" PATHS ENV SDL2DIR)
```

---

If you feel that SDL2 developers could rename the problematic file, but expect that file to be near the `SDL2.h`, then you could change the above command to search `SDL2.h` instead of `begin_code.h`:

```
find_path(SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR_1 "SDL2.h" PATH_SUFFIXES "SDL2" PATHS ENV SDL2DIR)
```